# How to have 3 sets of layout resources for Android

Tags: android, layout, drawable

I'd like to have 3 sets of layouts and 3 sets of drawables for 480x854, 540x960, and 720x1280.

How would I go about naming my resource folders to accomodate this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How about *drawable-normal*(480x854), *drawable-large*(540x960), *drawable-xlarge*(720x1280)?

Answer (score 0):

The three sets of drawables can be placed under the resources directory [res] in the following  folders `res/drawable-hdpi`, `res/drawable-ldpi` and `res/drawable-mdpi` .

Comment: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi are for resolution, not for size, A small size device can have high resolution(hdpi) ex `sony xperia` and same way large size device can have low resolution(mdpi) ex. `macromax Funbook`.